# Найти угол между отрезком с координатами (0,0)-(x,y) и осью Oy

Tags: математика, геометрия

Допустим, есть точка (0;1), угол = 0. Это точка отсчета. Вращаю точку вокруг начала координат по часовой стрелке и хочу получить угол от 0 до 360 (он же 0). То есть от точки (-1;0) угол будет равен 270.

Понимаю, что это элементарно, но голова другим забита и некогда вспоминать азы тригонометрии. Может, кто-то сможет ответить сходу?

Comment: Хотите получить - получите. Совершенно не ясно что на входе и что должно быть на выходе.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, что непонятного то? На входе координаты точки, на выходе угол.

Comment: Написано непонятно. Тангенс угла будет равен y/x, это между отрезком и Ox. Для Oy вычесть полученный угол из 90 градусов.

Comment: 90 - y/x? А дальше? Мне нужен угол от 0 до 360.

Comment: А дальше - арифметика, к тому же не ясно в какую сторону отсчет - по часовой или против.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, русским языком написано - по часовой

Comment: Этот вопрос и, особенно, ответ на него - прекрасная иллюстрация бедственного положения в программировании в современном мире.

Comment: @Igor, вы путаете программирование и тригонометрию

Comment: @iRumba - Спасибо, я не нуждаюсь в дополнительных иллюстрациях.

Comment: @Igor, не знаю, в чем вы там нуждаетесь, но свои комментарии на темы "что делать" и "как дальше жить" клепайте в собственном блоге. Здесь обсуждается конкретная тема

Comment: @iRumba - Как быстро современный человек скатывается к хамству.

Comment: @Igor, и к осуждению. Осудил - получил ответ. Все просто.

Comment: @iRumba - Кто же тут осуждает? Констатирует.

Comment: @Igor, в чем тут констатация? Ее основа выдумана. Вы говорите тут о проблемах с программированием, когда в тегах темы явно указано "Математика", "Геометрия"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Делаешь поворот на 90 градусов, чтобы точкой отсчёта была горизонтальная ось.
2. Вызываешь `atan2`.

Эти пункты можно совместить:

```
double res = atan2(-x, y) * 180 / PI;
if(res<0) res += 360;
```

Comment: Я хочу получить конкретную формулу. Мне это в код еще переводить. Я не могу резко переключиться с программирования на тригонометрию (так уж вышло). Оформите пожалуйста ответ так, чтобы была формула или набор очередность формул, на входе которых координаты точки, на выходе угол от 0 до 360. Я не понимаю что значит "делаешь поворот"

Comment: @iRumba, ответ обновлён. Надеюсь, не ошибся.

Comment: на входе точка (-1,0), на выходе -90. Ожидалось 270 :(

Comment: вместо -y поставил y. В суть не вникал, просто опытным путем. Потому что в точке 0;1 возвращало 180 вместо 0

Comment: В моем случае получилось так `Math.Atan2(x, y) * 180 / Math.PI + (x >= 0 ? 0 : 360)`. В общем виде ang = atan2(x, y) * 180 / PI. Если (x<0), то ang += 360. Может как то красивее надо это описать. Оформите пожалуйста и я отмечу как ответ

Comment: @iRumba, 1. Так возьми и вникни. 2. Твоя формула неверна. 3. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Почему неверна, объясни пожалуйста? Она дает правильные ответы в тестах. Мне некогда вникать в это. Я вообще не понимаю почему программист должен быть физиком, химиком, математиком, биологом и географом. Если бы не было ресурсов, где я могу задать вопрос, пришлось бы вникать и тратить в N раз больше времени на написание кода.

Comment: Согласитесь, было бы проще, если бы каждый занимался своим делом. Когда то я решал подобные задачки в уме и сразу. Теперь все забыл. Остались только начальные знания и общее понимание, которых достаточно, чтобы вспомнить материал. Но я ведь занимаюсь другим делом. Сегодня мне понадобилась тригонометрическая формула, завтра потребуется знание электротехники. Так что не осуждайте меня, я не ленивый, просто у меня не так много времени, как хотелось бы.

Comment: @iRumba, попробуй точку (1, 2).

Comment: Так и твоя формула не работает

Comment: @iRumba, не заметил, что ты по часовой стрелке хочешь. Вычти результат из 360.

Answer (score 1):

Просто арктангенс даёт аргумент от -90 до +90 градусов. Чтобы не возиться с логикой квадрантов, лучше исходить из арктангенса половинного аргумента:

1. r = sqrt (x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup>).
2. Если r+x = 0, то fi = 180,
   Иначе fi = 2arctg ( y / (r + x) ) (в градусах)
3. fi -= 90
4. Если fi<0, то fi += 360.

Первые два пункта дают арктангенс (-180, +180]; пп. 3-4 - пожелания ТС.